# Жерло́ или же́рло?

Tags: этимология, орфоэпия

И там же я увидел, что правильно говорить **жерло́**.
Почему же тогда никогда никто так не говорит? Везде и всегда говорят ***в же́рле*** вулкана.

Answer (score 1):

Говорят жерлО. Те, кто говорит правильно. 
А смещение происходит только во множественном числе: жЕрла. Возможно отсюда и массовая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Русское словесное ударение:
**жерло́, -а́**; *мн.* же́рла, жерл [*не* ё]

Орфографический словарь:
**жерло́, -а́**, *мн.* же́рла, жерл

Большой толковый словарь:
[**жерло́**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%E6%E5%F0%EB%EE), **-а́**; ***мн.*** же́рла, жерл; **ср.**
**1.** *чего.* Узкое, глубокое отверстие. *Ж. трубы. Ж. тоннеля. Ж. подземной дороги. Ж. вулкана* (отверстие в вулканической горе, кратере вулкана). **//** Входное отверстие печи. *Раскалённые жерла доменных печей. Огнедышащее ж. печи.* **/** О самой горячей точке, месте, самом пекле чего-л. *Танки шли на запад, в самое ж. войны.*
2. Дуло, переднее отверстие ствола артиллерийского орудия. *Орудийные жерла. Жерла корабельных пушек.*

Итак, издавна и поныне в слове "жерло" правила орфоэпии диктуют постановку ударения на последний слог – **жерло́.**
**В единственном числе ударение падает на последний слог во всех падежах.**
Основная путаница — как правильно ставить ударение? — возникает из-за того, что во множественном числе оно смещается на первый слог (же́рла).

В этимологическом словаре Г. А. Крылова:
[**жерло́**](https://lexicography.online/etymology/krylov/%D0%B6/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE) — это общеславянское слово, ныне имеющее значение «дульное отверстие ствола артиллерийского орудия», образовано от того же корня, что и *горло*, но ввиду особенностей развития с иными согласным и гласным звуками; первоначальный его вид **gьrdlo.**

Есть даже мнемонический стишок ("запоминалка"):
*У вулкана есть жерло́ —

Ох и жаркое оно!*

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, наша разговорная речь "насыщена" неправильным ударением и произношением (к примеру, жАлюзи вместо жалюзИ). Правильно жерлО, во мн. ч. жЕрла (не Ё).

Comment: жАлюзи через нета много лет признают допустимым. Всё к тому идёт. 
Но тут разные вещи. Жалюзи - позднее заимствование, ударение не устоялось. Жерло - собственно славянское, очень древнее.

Comment: С Вашими доводами согласна. Многие нынешние ошибки в дальнейшем станут нормой. Примеров тому - масса. Но на данный момент, не удаваясь в историю слов, ответы правильные. Дополнение: возможно, не мн. ч. дало повод для смещения ударения, а просто потому, что так проще употреблять. Кто знает!