# Ударение в слове "крепится"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Как правильно ставить ударение в третьем лице, если речь про крепёж чего-то, а не о значении *бодриться*?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/крепиться Но ставят на Е, другого не слышал.

Comment: Вот и я не слышал на И, а между тем в словарях такое ударение!

Comment: Нелогично получается: не говорим же "кр**е**пились", только вот язык не любит подчиняться строгим законам.

Comment: И что? Будешь говорить не так, как все?

Comment: Да ты что, в своём ли уме?))

Comment: Просто спрашивают, чтобы потом использовать правильный вариант. Вдруг совесть не позволит говорить неправильно...

Comment: Спрашиваю, чтобы узнать мнение других. И прислушиваюсь к нему.

Comment: Ну это радует, а то мне показалось, что настолько правильный, что готов говорить по-другому.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрим, что имеется в словарях, которые имеются у меня (не правьте — так задумано).

Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Р. И. Аванесова (С. Н. Борунова, В. Л. Воронцова, Н. А. Еськова. АН СССР. ИРЯ. 1989):

> **крепи́ть,** -плю́, -пи́т, *прич. страд прош.* креплённый, -ён, -ена́, *см. § 24* **!** *неправ.* кре́пит
> **крепи́ться,** -плю́сь, -пи́тся **!** *неправ.* кре́пится

Словарь ударений для работников радио и телевидения под ред. Д. Э. Розенталя (Ф. Л. Агеенко, М. В. Зарва. 1967):

> крепи́ть(ся), -плю́(сь), -пи́шь(ся)

В орфографических (110 тысяч слов, 1957; 25 тысяч слов, 2003):

> (1) **крепи́ть(ся),** -плю́(сь), -пи́шь(ся)
> (2) **крепи́ть(ся),** -плю́(сь), -пи́т(ся), *несов.*

Получается, что правильно говорить так:
*К большой коробке крепи́тся красивый белый бант.

Мелкие детали крепя́тся к основному устройству с помощью специальных зажимов.*

Вполне возможно, что устоявшийся перенос ударения на "е" (*кре́пится*) связан со словами *крепь, крепкий, крепко*. Как известно, приставки (кроме *вы-*) не изменяют ударения в глаголах, поэтому необходимо произносить *закрепи́тся, прикрепи́тся, открепи́тся, укрепи́тся.*

P. S. Спасибо за вопрос (век живи — век удивляйся собственному языку и собственным привычкам. Как со словом [*жерло́*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/12178/%D0%96%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE%CC%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B5%CC%81%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE)).

Comment: Спасибо и за ответ, Рим! С приставками-то я как раз и говорю на окончание. ;)

Comment: "Укрепится" из другой оперы, никто на Е ударение не поставит.

Comment: Еще как поставит! Возможно, что вы — счастливчик! — к этим "никто" и относитесь, но в ОСРЯ не зря отмечено: **укрепи́ться,** -плю́сь, -пи́тся **!** *неправ.* укре́пится.

Comment: Ну ок, но звучит ужасно, просто у этого слова другое значение (не связанное с крепежом). Больше 30 лет прошло, возможно, что этот неправильный вариант уже не используется.

Answer (score 2):

Мне ситуация видится таким образом.

1. Глагол ***крепИться***, указанный в словаре Кузнецова, имеет значение держать себя в руках, бодриться:

**КРЕПИТЬСЯ,** -плюсь, -пИшься; нсв. 1. **Держать себя в руках**; сдерживаться. Я долго крепился, но не выдержал и расхохотался. Она не могла больше к. и заплакала. 2. **Бодриться**. Неприятности следовали одна за другой, но он крепился.

2. Но есть еще глагол ***крепИть***, имеющий **страдательный (пассивный)**  залог ***крепИться***, причем ударение в этой форме в толковом словаре Кузнецова указано также **на И**:

**КРЕПИТЬ**,  1. что (чем). Прочно **прикреплять, соединять**; скреплять элементы машин, конструкций. К. рельсы к шпалам. К. леса для строительных работ. К. сваи железными скобами. К. канат. К. снасть. <**КрепИться, -Ится; страд.**

3. **Страдательный залог** имеет следующие формы: инфинитив ***крепИться***, все формы прошедшего времени (***крепИлись*** и др.) и только **две формы** настоящего времени **для 3-го лица**: ***крЕпится, крЕпятся.*** (Формы 1-го и 2-го лица отсутствуют для страдательного значения.)
4. Указанные словарные нормы ударения **на И в орфоэпических словарях** относятся только к глаголу ***крепИться*** (= бодриться).

Почему? Вот, к примеру, словарь Резничено за 2010 год: крепить(ся), **креплю(сь), крепИшь(ся). (неправ. крЕпишься)**. Обратим внимание: названы нормы  для 1-го и 2-го лица, а у страдательного залога ***крепиться*** (= прикреплять) этих форм нет.

5. В реальной речи страдательные формы с ударением на первом слоге **явно присутствуют**, иногда они обозначены даже на учебных сайтах [Как правильно](https://kak-pravilno.net/krepitsya-ili-krepitsya-kak-pravilno/)

Но им противостоят **орфоэпические словари**, рекомендации которых, скорее всего, относятся только к ***крепИться*** (= бодриться).
Носители же языка склонны **различать две формы** слова (активную и пассивную) с разным значением. Поэтому устоявшийся **перенос ударения на Е** кажется вполне естественным.

5. Пока же остается **наблюдать за процессом**. Но удивляет мнение пользователей, уверенно ссылающихся на словари и отстаивающих такое произношение.  А там написано: **неправ. крЕпишься для 2-го лица**. Это, конечно, неправильно.

Я креплЮсь, ты крепИшься, он крепИтся (= бодрится), в этом нет сомнения, но  вот предмет болтами и зажимами именно ***крЕпится.*** Это выбор носителей языка, доверяющих своей интуиции. Вспомним **их мнение**:

*— Но ставят на Е, другого не слышал.*

*— Вот и я не слышал на И, а между тем в словарях такое ударение!*

**P. S.** Не стоит в этой теме вспоминать про **приставочные** глаголы (***укрепиться*** и др.) — у них свое значение и свои грамматические формы. Это уже **непереходные**  глаголы совершенного вида, не имеющие пассивного залога (глаголы с частицей СЯ относятся к различным видам возвратного залога).

**В КАЧЕСТВЕ ИТОГА**

1. В языке существуют **два глагола** с разной грамматикой и значением.

(1) ***КрепИться*** (= бодриться): возвратный глагол, ударение везде на И.

Используется как обычный глагол **во всех формах**, в том числе в настоящем времени в трех лицах: я креплЮсь, ты крепИшься, он крепИтся, они крепЯтся.

(2) ***КрепИться*** (= про крепёж чего-то): пассивный залог глагола «крепить», колебание ударений в двух словоформах (на Е вместо И) .

Существуют все формы, **кроме 1-го  и 2-го лица** настоящего времени, а  в двух формах 3-го лица ударение переходит на первый слог: ***крЕпится, крЕпятся.***

2. Это имеет место в языке, но не отражено в словарях, в том числе в орфоэпических, где разницу в грамматике и значениях **просто не замечают.**
3. Формы ***крЕпится, крЕпятся***(со значением крепежа) желательно запомнить и узаконить в них ударение на Е.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140033/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).